# TexStudio highlighting

Tags: texstudio, r, knitr, syntax-highlighting

I'm using a number of `\Sexpr` statements in my `Rnw` file. They contain `$` symbols and this results in e.g.

[image: green highlighting]

The result is very messy green highlighting in inappropriate places and a hard to read file. Is there a way for TexStudio to ignore `$` within `\Sexpr` statements?

Answer (score 1):

Will be fixed in the next release.

<s>Until then, you can work around this by manually [changing the language definition](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#LANGUAGEDEF):</s>

1. Create a folder `languages` in your [settings directory](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#where-are-the-settings-stored)
2. Download the updated file [tex.qnfa](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/hg/ci/default/tree/utilities/qxs/tex.qnfa) and put it in this directory.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I tried your work around but it doesn't seem to make any difference. Can I check that I made the settings directory in the right place?  I made the directory as %APPDATA%\texstudio\languages, this is a subdirectory of the directory in which texstudio.ini resides. Do I need to do anything else in texstudio apart from restart?

Comment: Sorry. The workaround does actually not work because the languages are nested: tex highlighting is imported by sweave highlighting. However, these relative imports do not use the languages directory. If you really would want to make it work now, you'd have to download sweave.qnfa, put it in the languages directory and replace `<embed target="(La)TeX">` by the content of the `<QNFA>` tag in tex.qnfa. It's a bit of a mess though.

Comment: Hi, I installed texstudio-2.12.4-win-qt5.6.2.exe but still getting the same problem.